# VirtualBox: modprobe can't find vboxguest, vboxsf, vboxvideo

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I've been following [these instrctions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Install_the_Guest_Additions) to install the guest packages for arch linux.

Unfortunatelly `modprobe` returns:

```
[snooc@archfire ~]$ modprobe -a vboxguest vboxsf vboxvideo
modprobe: WARNING: Module vboxguest not found.
modprobe: WARNING: Module vboxsf not found.
modprobe: WARNING: Module vboxvideo not found.
```

`pacman -Ss virtualbox` is showing:

```
[snooc@archfire ~]$ pacman -Ss virtualbox
...
community/virtualbox-guest-modules 4.3.12-1 [installed]
    Guest kernel modules for VirtualBox
...
community/virtualbox-guest-utils 4.3.12-1 [installed]
    VirtualBox Guest userspace utilities
...
```

How can I fix this? I have no idea where to begin.

*Arch Linux is guest on VirtualBox which runs under Win7.*

Comment: Can you clarify if you're doing this on the host or on the guest OS?

Comment: My ArchLinux is guest. VirtualBox runs on Win7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when i was trying to install arch on virtualbox earlier today.
The solution is to run *depmod*

```
$ depmod 3.14.4-1-ARCH
```

After running *modprobe* again, it should work.

You can use `uname -r` to find your kernel version string.

[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181938%20%22Source)

Comment: this worked for me too! +1

Comment: The command in this answer didn't work for me, but what I did is I ran `pacman -Ql virtualbox-guest-modules` to find out where the modules are and then I ran `depmod` with arguments consisting of the paths to each module file (.ko.gz).  But I wonder why I have to do this junk at all; the guest additions were working fine before I upgraded my system this morning.

Comment: The full command that worked for me was `depmod \`uname -r\`` on CentOS 7.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I notice that the WIKI for this says that the `virtualbox-guest-modules` must be the same version as the `virtualbox` running on the host.  Upgrading your system _may_ have introduced an incompatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread that sounds like your issue. Titled: [Virtualbox guest module doesn't load](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135207).

*excerpt*

> Do you have the official virtualbox guest additions installed? You shouldn't do that. If so uninstall them and then install the package
>
> ```
>    $ sudo pacman -S virtualbox-archlinux-additions
>    $ sudo pacman -Qs virtualbox
> ```
>
> should give:
>
> ```
>    local/virtualbox-archlinux-additions 4.1.8-2
>    local/virtualbox-archlinux-modules 4.1.8-3
> ```
>
> **Source:** Wiki: [ArchLinux Wiki - VirtualBox](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_steps_for_Arch_Linux_guests)

#### UPDATE #1

Per a comment left by @DavidGrayson the package names may have changed. So try these instead if the above do not work:

```
$ sudo pacman -S virtualbox-guest-modules-arch virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: There is no virtualbox-archlinux-additions package.  I think you meant virtualbox-guest-modules and virtualbox-guest-utils.

Comment: @DavidGrayson - that was an excerpt from the webpage that I referenced. I do not have access to archlinux so could not confirm any of this.

Comment: I think you might need to specify the kernel version too, like: `linux47-virtualbox-guest-modules`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have internet connection and DNS is working by using `ping archlinux.org`

run `pacman net-tools`  (follow onscreen direction to install)

then make sure you have a local IP (where you should have internet connection) when you run `ifconfig`

run `dhcpcd` command twice if there is an error first time.

run `pacman -Syu` to update package db

run `pacman -S virtualbox-guest-modules` and follow onscreen direction to install arch related files.

After that `modprobe -a vboxguest vboxsf vboxvideo` runs without any issues.

Comment: Can you explain how this differs from the existing answers?

Comment: sure, my issue was that i wasnt able to ping any website from domain name, and ip was working. 

I am assuming pacman wasnt able to resolve the virtualbox package name from default listing, running net-tools made it get new newer list of packages.